# How to initialize array of Map type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a simple and fast question, how to initialize an array of `Map` in TS?

Right now, I'm simply do this like here:

```
const someMap: Array<Map<string, string>> = new Array<Map<string, string>>();
```

but I have to use `[]` instead of `Array`:

```
const someMap: Map<string, string>[] = new Map<string, string>[];
```

can someone tell me why in above example TS throw me this?

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'Map<string, string>' has no index signature. Did you mean to call 'get'?
```

how to properly initialize `Map<string, string>[]`?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

[Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals) can be made with just brackets:

```js
const someMap: Map<string, string>[] = [];
```

Comment: Relevant documentation: this is an [array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals)

Answer (score 3):

It can be made like this as well:

```js
const someMap: Map<string, string>[] = [new Map<string, string>()]
```